# Chart.js : How to get a line created by sum of others line?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm actually using chart.js to make small chart like this :

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEh1E.png)

I have some integer values in y-axis and date in x-axis.
Here you can see an example of my dataset : [dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUY4l.png)

I want to add a new line, with as a value : the sum of the values ​​at each date.
My datasets are dynamically generated.
With the dataset I uploaded, the data of this line should be

```
0: Object { x: "2021-09-02", y: 20 }
​​1: Object { x: "2021-09-08", y: 13 }
​​​2: Object { x: "2021-09-08", y: 10 }
```

Can someone help me to get the loop which will sum that please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solutio

```js
var array = [
  { x: "2021-09-02", y: 20 },
  { x: "2021-09-08", y: 13 },
  { x: "2021-09-08", y: 10 },
];

var result = [];
array.reduce(function(res, value) {
  if (!res[value.x]) {
    res[value.x] = { x: value.x, y: 0 };
    result.push(res[value.x])
  }
  res[value.x].y += value.y;
  return res;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I succeed with your code, just needed to put all the values in one array.